# How to implement a while true loop correctly for two user inputs in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am writing code that will take an integer input from a user. If the integer is greater than 0 then the program will ask the user for a second integer input. If the second integer input is greater than 1 then the program will compute the first number raised to the power of the second number. I am unsure how to correctly implement a while true loop such that when a user enters a wrong input it will reprompt the user for that respective integer i.e. int 1 or 2. Really appreciate some help :)!

```py
while True:
    first_num= int(input("Enter the first integer:"))
    if(first_num>0):
     while True:        
        sec_num= int(input("Enter the second integer:"))
        if(sec_num>1):
            print(first_num**sec_num)
        break
```

Comment: Use *two separate loops*, or write a function that handles the loop and optionally sets additional constraints. See the duplicate for how to write a loop that properly validates, as well as wrap the whole in a function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - OP uses two loops. The problem is that the break is in the wrong place.

Comment: @tdelaney The loops aren't separate, though, they are nested.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that's okay if the intent is to keep repeating the process.

Comment: @tdelaney: so? this doesn't change how you should approach this.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `break` in the wrong place. Move it under the last `if` and it will continue prompting for the second number without going back to the first.

```
while True:
    first_num= int(input("Enter the first integer:"))
    if(first_num>0):
     while True:        
        sec_num= int(input("Enter the second integer:"))
        if(sec_num>1):
            print(first_num**sec_num)
            break
```

If you want to end the program after one success, then don't nest the whiles

```
while True:
    first_num= int(input("Enter the first integer:"))
    if(first_num>0):
        break

while True:        
    sec_num= int(input("Enter the second integer:"))
    if(sec_num>1):
        print(first_num**sec_num)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle each number one at a time. Don't start trying to get the second number until you have a valid first number.

```
while True:
    first_num = int(input(...))
    if first_num > 0:
        break

while True:
    second_num = int(input(...))
    if second_num > 1:
        break

print(first_num ** second_num)
```

If you want to repeat the `**` operation for multiple numbers, put everything inside a *third* loop.

```
while True:
    while True:
        first_num = int(input(...))
        if first_num > 0:
            break

    while True:
        second_num = int(input(...))
        if second_num > 1:
            break

    resp = input("Try again?")
    if not resp.lower().startswith("y"):
        break
```

Comment: It looks to me like OP wants to keep repeating the process. If so, nested loops are reasonable.

Comment: The logic for repeating the process should be kept separate from the logic of getting valid inputs.